# What is the space complexity of an AVL tree insert?

Tags: avl-tree, space-complexity

Wouldn't AVL inserts be O(logn) space, because you need logn stack frames to do inserts? AVL tree itself is O(n) space and time to insert is O(logn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the balancing property, the insertion, deletion and search operations take ***O(logn)*** in both the average and the worst cases. Therefore, AVL trees give us an edge over Binary Search Trees which have an ***O(n)*** time complexity in the **worst case** scenario.

The space complexity of an AVL tree is O(n) in both the average and the worst case.

Comment: this doesn't address what I brought up about recursive calls which would take up logn stack frames. yes it is O(n) space because n nodes and rotations are done in place, that is the standard response. So either the stack frames arent considered as part of space complexity, or you implement iteratively to get O(n) space. But a recursive implementation of AVL insert should be logn, no?

Comment: whether it is recursive or iterative space is O(n) because of n nodes and also for balancing factor. In the recursive implementation, you have to traverse the tree and then insert the node, but all your previous nodes would still be there which were n